# How can I place an element at the top of a page using CSS?

Tags: html, css

Suppose I want to place a piece of text at the top of a page like this:

[image: bar]

How would I do this using only CSS?

Comment: right_click -> inspect_element

Comment: @Xander, in IE? Does it have that?

Comment: @TylerCrompton yeah , it's called "developer tools" `F-12` - though, chrome's tools are much better...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//same place when scrolling:
position:fixed;
//just stay at the top
position:absolute;

top: 5px;
left: 5px;
```

Note: for absolute, make sure it is not inside an element with `position:relative;` or just place it directly inside the BODY tag

Answer (score 2):

Check this, it's how I learned css positioning. However I must say you should have googled first, it's the second result, and the first is still good:

http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

```
#div-1a {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I still end up in that site every now and then haha

Answer (score 2):

Try using it. Adjust with top/left attributes.

```
<div class="textToTop">
    Text here.
</div>

.textToTop {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, one is using absolute positioning:

http://jsfiddle.net/WHu7h/

```
<div class="toolbar">element positioned absolutely</div>

.toolbar { position:absolute; top:0; background:#ccc; }​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
<li><a href=#>Item</a></li>
<li><a href=#>Item</a></li>
<li><a href=#>Item</a></li>
<li><a href=#>Item</a></li>
<li><a href=#>Item</a></li>
<li><a href=#>Item</a></li>
<li><a href=#>Item</a></li>
<li><a href=#>Item</a></li>
<li><a href=#>Item</a></li>
<li><a href=#>Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

​

And the css

```
ul li{

 float: left;
 margin-right: 8px;    

}
​
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/h3gxu/)